# Problem while creating table with sqLite

Tags: android-emulator

i created one demo in android regarding the database. 
But while executing it facing some problem.
So can any one please help me.
Here is the code that i developed.

```
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataBaseWork extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String MY_DATABASE_NAME="TradeMarket";
        String MY_DATABASE_TABLE="shares";

        String data="DataBase";

        SQLiteDatabase myDB=null;
        try{

            myDB=this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "(LastName VARCHAR,FirstName VARCHAR,country VARCHAR,age INT(3));");


            /* Code to insert data in to DATABSE*/
            myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "(LastName,FirstName,country,age)"+ "VALUES('JOSHI','ANUP','INDIA',24);");

            myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "(LastName,FirstName,country,age)"+ "VALUES('JALKOTKAR','SACHIN','FRANCE',25);");

            /*CODE TO FETCH DATA FROM DATABASE */
            Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE ,null);

            int LastNameIndex=c.getColumnIndex("LastName");
            int FirstNameIndex=c.getColumnIndex("FirstName");
            int CountryIndex=c.getColumnIndex("country");
            int AgeIndex=c.getColumnIndex("age");

                c.moveToFirst();
                if(c!=null){

                        do{
                            String FirstName=c.getString(FirstNameIndex);
                            String LastName=c.getString(LastNameIndex);
                            String country=c.getString(CountryIndex);
                            int Age=c.getInt(AgeIndex);
                            data=data +FirstName + "/" + LastName + "/" + country + "/" + Age + "\n";
                            }while(c.moveToNext());
                    }

                            TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
                            tv.setText(data); 
                            setContentView(tv); 
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Error", e); 
               } finally { 
                if (myDB != null) 
                 myDB.close(); 
               } 
    }//end of onCreate method.
}// end of DataBaseWork.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` ? Note the ending "S".

Also note @Marcelo's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "(LastName,...
```

Will produce SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTshares(LastName,...
```

Likewise:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "(LastName,...
```

will become this:

```
INSERT INTOshares(LastName,...
```

Same for `myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + MY_DATABASE_TABLE`.

Also note @thelost's answer.